# How to debug a cmake/make project in VSCode?

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, gdb, g++

I'm making a project and in order to assist in building, I'm using `CMake`.

However, I notice that I can't debug.

Here's my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": "./build/bin/CHIP8",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd build && cmake .. && make"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't find anything online to help with this problem, so I'm really not sure where to go from here. VSCode docs has an example to debug where they use g++, but I'm using make --- so I'm not sure how to do it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you built release version of your program. Try to build debug version of your program.

```
rm -r build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
cmake --build .
```

It is better to separate debug and release builds.

```
mkdir Debug
cd Debug
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
cmake --build .
```

With appropriate update of `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "cppgdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": "./Debug/bin/CHIP8",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Updated "type" according to VS Code updates. `"type": "gdb"` was previously*

Comment: I tried this and I get an error saying: Configured debug type 'gdb' is not supported.

Version info
------------------
Version: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:39:46.686Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.13.0-25-generic snap

Comment: @RaleighL. MS as always broke it with updates. Try "cppdbg". If it works I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, even I use cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .., it still cannot work, I need to set below flags in my cmakefile.

> set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -DDEBUG")
>   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -DDEBUG")