# How to setup VSCode debugger to work with cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583381/how-to-debug-a-cmake-make-project-in-vscode) that is pretty close, but the C++ extension has been updated since then and the `launch.json` file that is created for you is very different and I'm not sure how to set it up. There also isn't a lot of info online to do this, so I'm hoping someone has done this before. My current project structure is like this:

```
MainProj
   ./build
   CMakeLists.txt
   main.cpp
   otherClasses.hpp
```

And the cmake target that shows up in `build` after running `..cmake` and `make` is called `Main`.

launch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the tasks.json file from the other question

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd build && cmake .. && make"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Debugger is not supposed to deal with cmake anyhow.

Comment: Which extensions are you using, and what OS?  If you do not have it, try the [cmake-tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools).