# CMake cross compiling execute custom script to flash binary into target machine

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I'm running `cmake` on VSCode. I'm trying to set it up to invoke a custom script I wrote to flash the executable into my target mcu.

I'm reading about `CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR`, `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` and `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING` but I can't find an example of how to use them properly.

The main issue is that after the building is complete `cmake` is trying to run the `*.elf` file.

How can I flash the binary after building?

Comment: You want to flash the result of compilation _or_ run tests on your target? How do you "flash the executable into my target mcu" without cmake?

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to flash the result of compilation on my target mcu. I have a script that does that and I execute it manually after each build. I want to invoke that script from cmake after building

Comment: The target's property [CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR.html) affects only the way how executable will be used in `COMMAND` clauses of CMake commands like `add_test` or `add_custom_command`. Variable `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` is additionally used in `try_compile`. In VSCode you need to specify **command line** to be used as "run" action. In that command line you could do whatever you want: run your script, pass it parameters, etc. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583381/how-to-debug-a-cmake-make-project-in-vscode

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, that's what I want. But I haven't found the way to do it yet.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think  you cannot change the action takes place after hitting "run" button in cmake extension of vscode.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a script that does that and I execute it manually after each build. I want to invoke that script from cmake after building

Generally:

```
add_executable(the_executable_target ...)
add_custom_target(flashit
    COMMAND
          ${YOUR_INTERPRETER_LIKE_BASH_OR_SOMTHING}
          ./your_script 
          $<TARGET_FILE:the_executable_target>
    COMMENT "flashes it"
)
add_dependencies(flashit the_executable_taregt)
```

You could add `ALL`. You could also interest in `add_custom_commnad(POST_BUILD ...`.

`CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` is used for `try_run`, but most importantly for running tests.

Comment: No, it won't work. It still tries to run `my_executable.elf` after `cmake --build`, instead of my script